# How to take input for Java Web Application through a Java Application?

Tags: java, web-applications

I am trying to do some operation on two folders .

Actually i am trying to develop a application which by using diff command can tell me whether these file differ or not.

Till now while writing the code for it i was using defining path of folder manually.

```
e.g. String path1 = "C:\\Users\\hi\\Downloads\\IIT Typing\\IIT Typing"; 

        String path2 = "C:\\Users\\hi\\Downloads\\IIT Typing\\IIT Typing";
```

Now As i am developing a java application i want user to select folders automatically through a button which will let him select two folders.

Comment: Vague and ununderstandable.

Comment: If you are referring to configurations, then you can point both applications to same database. Likewise can be done with properties files too. Doing so will enable other application to read changes done by first. Hope i understood your problem right.

Comment: You need to define the problem space at a more detailed level, as well as creating a well defined query that fits the aforementioned issue.  i.e. huh?

Comment: @MarounMaroun : Sorry i am going to edit it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to do this graphically you want 2 jfile choosers embedded in a jpanel.  They will pick the two paths and then pick a button "go" or whatever.

```
    JFileChooser fc1 = ....
    JFileChooser fc1 = ....
    JButton button ...
    JPanel panel ...
    pabel.add(fc1);
    panel.add(fc2);
    panel.add(button);
```

Then a few action listeners to listen for the picking and the button and to do the right thing,
maybe a JTextPanel to display the results etc.

Hope this gets you pointed in the right direction.